# Javascript auto click submit button without reload the page

Tags: submit

Simple code to automatically click submit button.

```
document.forms["myform"].submit();
```

I already have ajax code when this button is click.
However, it will refresh the page. May I know how to prevent page reload and it will still run the code?

Comment: Why do you need to programatically click the button? What's wrong with just calling the function that you run when it is clicked?

Answer (score -1):

Have your ajax code that is running when the button is clicked call `event.preventDefault()` and `return false`.

**Edit:**

```js
document.getElementById("yourButtonID").onclick = function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  
  // your ajax code here
  
  return false;
}
```

Comment: I need some code to automatically click the button as well.

Comment: I edited my post to include an example of how to automatically click the button.

Answer (score -1):

.submit() will refresh the page, you will have to use ajax submits like $.ajax or $.post.

Use examples from here: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

Comment: I need some code to automatically click the button as well.

Comment: did you try using $( "form" ).trigger( "submit" );